# factory girl nested factory

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

I have an account model that belongs_to a role model.

```
factory :role do
  name "student"
end

factory :account do
  user
  role
end
```

The first factory creates a role named "student".  The second factory creates an account that is associated to the student role that was created in the previous factory.  It also is associated with a user...which is not important for this question.

I have many roles to be tested (admin, student, assistant)...  I dont want to specify 'student' in the role factory...thats too static.  How do I specify what role to create at the time the account factory is created?  Like:

```
  factory :account do
    user
    role_id { factory :role { name: "admin"} }
  end
```

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you want a purely FG solution, you could use Traits:

```
factory :account do
  user

  trait :student do
    association :role, :name => "student"
  end

  trait :admin do
    association :role, :name => "admin"
  end
end

FactoryGirl.create :account, :student
FactoryGirl.create :account, :admin
```

However, you can override the properties of the factory when you create the factory object. This allows for more flexibility:

```
FactoryGirl.create(:account,
  :role => FactoryGirl.create(:role, :name => "student")
)
```

Since this is obviously verbose, I'd create a little helper method:

```
def account_as(role, options = {})
  FactoryGirl.create(:account,
    options.merge(:role => FactoryGirl.create(:role, :name => "student"))
  )
end
```

Then in your tests:

```
let(:account) { account_as "student" }
```

Alternately, you could just shorten up your role generator so you could use it like:

```
def role(role, options = {})
  FactoryGirl.create :role, options.merge(:name => role)
end

account = FactoryGirl.create :account, :role => role("student")
```