# Attributes_for Ruby on Rails 4 tests with factory girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I'm trying to test simple POST controller#create method.

```
it "saves the new object in the DB" do
  object = build(:object_with_association)
  expect { post :create, object: object.attributes }.to change(SomeObject, :count).by(1)
end
```

Is this **object.attributes** is the best way to do this? I tried to use attributes_for(:object_with_association), but it returns a hash without associations at all. May be there is some useful method to do this inside expect?
My factory:

```
factory :obj do
  name "A"
  association :first, factory: :first
  association :second, factory: :second

  factory :obj_with_association do
    transient do
      nested_count 5
    end

    after(:build) do |obj, evaluator|
      create_list(:nested, evaluator.nested_count, obj: obj)
    end
  end
end
```

Association for the :first and :second is **belongs_to**, for the :nested is **has_many**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create attributes separately and merge them, or you can try traits with FactoryGirl.

Please take a look at these two SO questions for details:

- [factory girl nested factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14093293/factory-girl-nested-factory)
- [Using FactoryGirl to create a parameter string for controller testing with related models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33807690/using-factorygirl-to-create-a-parameter-string-for-controller-testing-with-relat/33808073)